# How to grant permission to new user created in mysql?

Tags: mysql, permissions, users

I want to create new user and want to give them specific permission like inset, update and delete.
But how to create new user and give them permission i don't know.

Any help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be something like this :

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON database TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

To see a list of the privileges that have been granted to a specific user:

```
select * from mysql.user where User='username';
```

OR

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you so much. Let me try another one also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GRANT syntax to give user permission:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

For example if you would like to give SELECT permission on TEST database for myUser then:

*GRANT SELECT ON `Test`.* TO 'myUser'@'%';*